# Why my RecyclerView doesnt show anything?

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a big issue.
My `RecyclerView` doesnt work and I don´t know how to solve my problem.
In my Logcat it seems that the Fragment doesn't call `onResponse` and only call the `ErrorResponse`.
I tried everything but nothing helped at all.
Don't know which part is wrong and why it doesnt work.

My Home Fragment:

```
public class Home_Fragment extends Fragment {
private String URL= "http://localhost/pages/index.php";
private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<Data> listdata;
private static final String TAG = "Home_Fragment";


private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
public Home_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
private void AmbilData() {
    JsonArrayRequest aarRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length()>0){
                for (int i =0 ; i<response.length();i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Data item = new Data();
                        item.setEventname(data.getString("Eventname"));
                        item.setEventhost(data.getString("Eventclub"));
                        item.setEventclub(data.getString("Eventhost"));
                        item.setGenre(data.getString("Genre"));
                        item.setDate(data.getString("Date"));
                        item.setAdress(data.getString("Adress"));
                        item.setTime(data.getString("Time"));
                        item.setPrice(data.getString("Price"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
                recyclerAdapter.addData(listdata);
            }
        }
        },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                }
                            }){

                    };
                    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(aarRequest);
                }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: createview");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_, container, false);

    AmbilData();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    listdata = new ArrayList<Data>();
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),listdata);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: viewreturned");

    return view;
}
}
```

My RecyclerAdapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Data> listdata;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "Recycler";

public RecyclerAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Data> listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: create Holder");
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.event_cardview, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Create holder Items");
    //holder.mImage.setImageResource(listdata.get(position).getThubnail());
    holder.eventname.setText(listdata.get(position).getEventname());
    holder.eventclub.setText(listdata.get(position).getEventclub());
    holder.eventhost.setText(listdata.get(position).getEventhost());
    holder.genre.setText(listdata.get(position).getGenre());
    holder.date.setText(listdata.get(position).getDate());
    holder.adress.setText(listdata.get(position).getAdress());
    holder.time.setText(listdata.get(position).getTime());
    holder.price.setText(listdata.get(position).getPrice());


}
public void addData(List<Data> data) {
    listdata.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: return size");
    return listdata.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CardView cv;
    private TextView eventname,eventclub,eventhost,genre,date,adress,time,price;
    private static final String TAG = "Class";


    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolder: created");
        cv=(CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventcardview);
        eventname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.EventName);
        eventclub=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.EventClub);
        eventhost=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.EventHost);
        genre=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Genre);
        date=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.dark);
        adress=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.location_adress);
        time=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Time);
        price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Price);

    }
}

}
```

My Data

```
public class Data {
    private String eventname;
    private String eventclub;
    private String eventhost;
    private String genre;
    private String date;
    private String adress;
    private String time;
    private String price;

public String getEventname() {
    return eventname;
}
public void setEventname(String eventname) {
    this.eventname = eventname;
}

public String getEventclub() {
    return eventclub;
}
public void setEventclub(String eventlcub) {
    this.eventclub = eventclub;
}

public String getEventhost() {
    return eventhost;
}
public void setEventhost(String eventhost) {
    this.eventhost = eventhost;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}
public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getAdress() {
    return adress;
}

public void setAdress(String adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

}
```

When I open localhost/pages/index.php on my Computer it shows this:

```
 {"ID":1,"Eventname":"Imagine-Event","Eventclub":"Imagine-Club","Eventhost":"Imagine-Host","Genre":"Techno","Date":"2020-12-31","Time":"22:00-06:00","Adress":"Frankfurt Gutleutstra\u00dfe 126a","Price":15}
{"ID":2,"Eventname":"Hello-Event","Eventclub":"Hello-Club","Eventhost":"Hello-Host","Genre":"Hello","Date":"2021-01-01","Time":"21:00-6:00","Adress":"Frankfurt am Main Sachsenhausengasse 128a","Price":5}
{"ID":3,"Eventname":"Fantasy-Event","Eventclub":"Fantasy-Club","Eventhost":"Fantasy-Host","Genre":"Mainstream","Date":"2021-02-19","Time":"00:00-12:00","Adress":"Langen (Hessen) Sehretstra\u00dfe 33a","Price":5}
{"ID":4,"Eventname":"This Event","Eventclub":"This-Club","Eventhost":"This Host","Genre":"Hip-Hop","Date":"2021-03-03","Time":"20:00-2:00","Adress":"Frankfurt am Main Goethestra\u00dfe","Price":15}
```

When I start it dont show the Recyclerview what is the problem tried to solve it for 10 hours now.

Comment: WHat error is the onError returning?  There's data about the problem in there.

Comment: Actually I can tell you-  the URL is wrong.  Localhost would be the phone itself, not the PC your server runs on.  Even if its an emulator, the emulator runs a virtual machine.  You need to use the actual IP of the server (or DNS name, but you likely don't have one).

Comment: Thank you for your answer I changed the URL but it dont work for now it seems that the if line isnt call while running added some LOG and only the ErrorResponse LOG is called.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding empty data to the `RecyclerView` adapter when you call `recyclerAdapter.addData(listdata)`  in `AmbilData()` method because you iterate over the `JSON` list and didn't add items to `listdata` list of data.

To solve this, use `listdata.add(item)` within the loop.

```
private void AmbilData() {
    JsonArrayRequest aarRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            if (response.length()>0){
                for (int i =0 ; i<response.length();i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Data item = new Data();
                        item.setEventname(data.getString("Eventname"));
                        item.setEventhost(data.getString("Eventclub"));
                        item.setEventclub(data.getString("Eventhost"));
                        item.setGenre(data.getString("Genre"));
                        item.setDate(data.getString("Date"));
                        item.setAdress(data.getString("Adress"));
                        item.setTime(data.getString("Time"));
                        item.setPrice(data.getString("Price"));
                        listdata.add(item); // <<<<<< Here is the Change

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    }
                }
                recyclerAdapter.addData(listdata);
            }
...
```

Also as @Gabe Sechan pointed out in comments, you have to check the `URL`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the URL and also added your line. Unfortunately it dont solve my problem, added a few LOG right before the if line and some inside the if line. It seems that it don´t run the if line and jumps to ErrorResponse without using the if line. Dont know what could also be wrong when I use the URL on my phone it works but on the emulator it shows nothing inside the Homefragment in the application

Comment: I added a new LOG at the getCount method to see if something is counted but it throws me only a 0 seems my Adapter dont get any Data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I got at the getItemcount method the size null cause my PHP-code was wrong.
I didnt throw out the right variables.

My Code:
`

```
?php foreach ($events AS $event):
         $ID=json_encode($events);
         print($ID);
endforeach; ?>
```

Before I used $event now im using $events as param.

`